# How to deal with xor conditions, rails, foreign keys and a sqlite database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, database-design, xor

What I want is, building this somehow with Rails 3.1:
[image: UML]

If `A` has set an id for `b_id`, it shouldn't be possible to setting an id for `c_id`. And for sure vice versa too.

I wish I could do at the database level from a migration (check constraint?). Is this somehow possible?
Or is it more affordable to do this in the model with validations?

My environment:

- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.1.3
- SQLite 3.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this through polymorphic associations, altho the schema won't look exactly like what you have, you can accomplish the same goal, having an item `A` belong to either a `B` or a `C` but never to both.

You can read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

In the example given on that link, `A` is their `Picture`, and `Employee` and `Proudct` are your `B` and `C`:

(copied from source linked above):

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In combination with @Frederick's answer, I'll get a complete solution to my questions.

Comment: I would agree more with @mynameiscoffey's answer. Have just one column for the foreign key in table `A`, hence we have `imageable_id` and `imageable_type` in table A

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely write validations for this - it's easier to provide good error messages to a user from a validations. I'd also like to back it up with a database constraint. It looks like check constraints can indeed do the job.

Rails has no support for this that I could find so you'll need to create the table with raw sql. You'll also need to change the schema dumper to `:sql` as rails won't be able to produce a `schema.rb` that describes this actually.

I wrote this migration

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    execute <<SQL
      CREATE TABLE foos (
        id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
        x_id INTEGER,
        y_id INTEGER,
        constraint xorit check( (x_id OR y_id) AND NOT(x_id AND y_id))
      )
SQL
  end
end
```

Then in the rails console

```
Foo.create(:x_id => 1, :y_id => 1) #=> SQLite3::ConstraintException
```

As it is you can create a row with neither x_id nor y_id set. You could change this by changing the constraint,

```
(x_id IS NOT NULL OR y_id IS NOT NULL ) AND (x_id IS NULL OR y_id IS NULL)
```

seemed to work for me

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In combination with @mynameiscoffey's answer, I'll get a complete solution to my questions.